# Prove Proposition I.7 of Euclids for the case where D lies in the interior of triangle ABC

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Prove that Given triangle ABC with apex C, we cannot construct another triangle ABD with D lying in the interior of ABC

Is this proven the same way as if D lies on the same side of AB?

I have it started as:
Given Triangle ABC we want to show that no other triangle can be formed. With some side length AB. Proof by contradiction, so we assume there is a point D not = to C inside of the triangle. Forming the triangle ABD with DB=CB and DA=Ca. Assume that D lies opposite of B and inside AC. So we draw DC forming the isosceles triangle BCD.

That is the point i have gotten to, and I am unsure if it correct or where exactly to go from here.

Comment: Again, this site is not designed to solve your homeworks. Please add your thoughts about the problems you propose.

Comment: As given, it is clearly possible to construct such a triangle. Euclid's proposition was that given lines (of length) AC and BC it is not possible to construct a second triangle base AB; a line of length AC starting at point A; and a line of length BC starting at point B.